# Get Static Property By the Name of the Property

Tags: c#, reflection

In `ImageFormat`, there are a few properties such as `Png`, `Tiff` etc.

Now, given a string is it possible to retrieve the corresponding static property?

Here's the code

```
[Test]
public void GetPng()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(ImageFormat.Png, GetImageFormat("Png"));  //how to construct a GetImageFormat function?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static ImageFormat GetImageFormat(string name)
{
    return (ImageFormat)typeof(ImageFormat)
        .GetProperty(name)
        .GetValue(null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void Main()
{
    typeof(ImageFormat).GetProperty("GetPng", BindingFlags.Public |
                                              BindingFlags.Static);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
PropertyInfo pi =  typeof(ImageFormat)
    .GetProperty("Png", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```